# Share Session between Apps in the same App Pool

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I have two applications in the same Application Pool: ASP.NET Web Forms and another ASP.NET MVC 4

Is it possible to share the ASP.NET session between both of these applications? If yes, what's needed to be configured?

Thank you,
Regards

Comment: You cannot share Sessions because a Session is a single instance. You can however use the [`Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx) object in place of Session to share data across the entire application pool

Comment: Can you guide me to an example on using Application object to share stuff across apps in the same app pool? Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594(v=vs.100).aspx